# res.send() too slow when returning large JSON object

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-stream

I am building an Express GET route that responds with a large JSON object.

Res.send(myobject) or res.json(myobject) works fine but is too slow.

Is there an alternative method that i can use?  I took a look at streaming but seemed to be file oriented.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Could you add more information? What is the object used to? Why is it so big? Did you try optmizing for repeated parameters?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could try JSONStream (https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream)

Comment: the object is a query response from ElasticSearch. its been trimmed to include only the relevant fields but is still large

Comment: ever manage to solve this ?